# Epsilon-Delta and Limits Approaching Infinity

Tags: calculus

According to the epsilon-delta definition of a limit, don’t we have to be able to say that if the value of x is within delta of the approaching value, then the value of of the expression must be within some epsilon of the limit?

How does this work for limits that approach infinity since there would be no finite value of delta?

Comment: If a "limit approaches infinity" your sequence is divergent and does not converge at all (in the usual metric on $\Bbb R$; note that $\infty$ is not even an element of $\Bbb R$)

Comment: @FrankieScheuer  Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition at infinity is different, notably we say that

$$\lim_{x\to x_0 }f(x)=\infty$$

when

$$\forall M\in \mathbb{R} \quad \exists \delta>0 \quad \forall x \quad |x-x_0|<\delta \quad f(x)>M$$

and similar for $-\infty$.

Note that if $x\to \infty$ the definition is

$$\forall M\in \mathbb{R} \quad \exists \delta>0 \quad \forall x >\delta \quad f(x)>M$$

and similar for $x\to -\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

For limits where your function goes to $\infty $ there is no $\epsilon $ involved.

The definition goes like this  $$  \forall M\in \mathbb{R} \quad \exists \delta>0 :\quad \forall x \quad |x-x_0|<\delta \implies  f(x)>M$$